# Cronjob not running when restart app or server

Tags: node.js, cron, cron-task

I have Cronjob use node_module: [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron)

```
var hello = function( ) {
    console.log('Hello world')
}

var job=new CronJob({cronTime:'00 52 13 * * *',

        // that's important (100% made up example):
    onTick: function() {
        hello({
            done: true,
            lastRun: new Date()
        });
    },

    start:false,timeZone:"America/Los_Angeles"});
job.start();
```

when I restart server .Cronjob not running.

Answer (score 0):

node scripts that uses node-cron still have to be started for the cronjob to run. Adding things to node-cron, does not add it to [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) on your machine, even though the naming can be confusing. node-cron simply allows your script to schedule jobs inside your script, while your script is running.

For this to work, either convert to scheduling the script on your machine, using the built in scheduler, or start your node script on machine startup. (This is different depending on your operating system).